# How to align left the matrix in bmatrix environment

Tags: align, matrices

In the following MWE, the A and B matrices are perfectly aligned. However, the  matrix C is aligning itself towards the right. How to align it towards the left?

```
  \begin{multline}
  A=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
-q_{0}&-q_{1}&-q_{2}&\cdots&-q_{n-1}
 \end{bmatrix}
  ,\,\,
  B=
  \begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   0  \\
   \vdots \\
    b_e
   \end{bmatrix}
   \\ 
  C =
  \begin{bmatrix}
   1 &b_1/b_0  &\cdots &b_{n-1}/b_0
   \end{bmatrix}
   \end{multline}
```

Comment: What is your desired result? Is it "to center the matrix in `bmatrix` environment" or "to align it [matrix C] towards the left"?

Comment: Align C towards left

Comment: Then how do you explain your title?

Comment: Sorry, by mistake. Done

Comment: `multiline` does not come with alignment.  I would guess its intent is to right align the 2nd line, as if it were the continuation of a long equation.  Perhaps you instead want some sort of `align` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You possibly want the row matrix to be centered with respect to the top block:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
A=\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
  -q_{0}&-q_{1}&-q_{2}&\cdots&-q_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
,\quad
B=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ b_e \end{bmatrix}
\\[2ex]
C = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & b_1/b_0 & \cdots & b_{n-1}/b_0 \end{bmatrix}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the equals signs to be aligned, use `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
A&=\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
  -q_{0}&-q_{1}&-q_{2}&\cdots&-q_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
,\quad
B=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ b_e \end{bmatrix}
\\[2ex]
C&=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & b_1/b_0 & \cdots & b_{n-1}/b_0 \end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `align*` instead of `multiline`.  Add some alignment tabs.

As commented, `multiline` does not come with alignment.  I would guess its intent is to right align the 2nd line, as if it were the continuation of a long equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
  A&=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
-q_{0}&-q_{1}&-q_{2}&\cdots&-q_{n-1}
 \end{bmatrix}
  ,\,\,
  B=
  \begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   0  \\
   \vdots \\
    b_e
   \end{bmatrix}
   \\[8pt]
  C &=
  \begin{bmatrix}
   1 &b_1/b_0  &\cdots &b_{n-1}/b_0
   \end{bmatrix}
   \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, instead of `\,\,`, you could replace with `&`, which would add more gap before the `B` matrix.